# UItableView cell automatic resize

Tags: swift, autolayout

I've been trying to solve this problem for almost a whole week, im trying to implement a table cell in which there are 5 static parameters, and 3 floating ones (their sizes can be larger or smaller, they may also not exist at all), I can't figure out these three parameters, I'm trying to hide the element, but that's all in vain, because of reuse everything breaks. Somewhere the height is more, somewhere less. How can I resolve this issue? Maybe it's easier for me to use different types of cells? here is my layout, 3 multicolored elements is what i am talking about. At the moment, each of them has constraints set to 0 to the nearest element (stackview and elements inside) and a height greater than or equal to. Thanks in advance

[UIStackView Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L4Et.png)

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWg1o.png)

[what does it really look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlmsO.png)

Comment: Are the red, green, gray frames ***labels***? And you will sometimes have text in green only, green and red only, or in all three?

Comment: In green, there is always text(is that UITextView), in red, text is larger/less/not at all, in gray, there is a collectionview of fixed sizes, but it is either there or not

Comment: *"In green, there is always text(is that UITextView)"* -- does your text view have a fixed Height constraint? Or, is scrolling disabled so it gets its Height from its text? (Is it editable?)

Comment: I can't fix its height, because it is also dynamic (attached a screenshot of the problem if you do not fix the height) the scroll is disabled. But even if I set it to a fixed height, there is empty space in other cells, which is removed only if I make the stackView smaller, but I can’t because it doesn’t get bigger when there is a lot of text.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a lot going on, and this should probably be a couple different questions, but here are some comments...

First, you said your stack view elements have *constraints set to 0 to the nearest element* ... you should allow the stack view to layout the elements - you should not be adding inter-element constraints.

Second, one of the big benefits of a stack view is that if you **hide** an element, the space it has taken is removed.

So, if your "middle" element is a multi-line label - I'll call it `redLabel` - and you set `redLabel.isHidden = true`, your stack view will do this:

[image]

If you then also set `.isHidden = true` on your bottom element (the collection view?), it will do this:

[image]

I slapped together a quick example that may help you on your way. It looks like this when running (cyan is the textView, red is a label, gray rects are the collection view cells):

[image]

For the first 3 rows, all 3 elements have data (so they are visible). Scrolling down, we show Row 3 without the red label, Row 4 without the collection view, and Row 5 with both of them hidden:

[image]

The text view has scrolling disabled, so it will size itself:

[image]

as the user types:

[image]

---

This is the source for `SizingCell.xib`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="19529" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="19519"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="238" id="61P-bN-2e0" customClass="SizingCell" customModule="SWiOS12" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="238"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="61P-bN-2e0" id="huS-tm-qA9">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="238"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" verticalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" text="Title Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="XQI-LW-mKN">
                        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="11" width="79" height="20.5"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45009386540000001" green="0.98132258650000004" blue="0.4743030667" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="2" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="bt1-hr-iCP">
                        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="39.5" width="374" height="187.5"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" scrollEnabled="NO" text="This is the text view" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="laq-Mt-rKJ">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="374" height="37.5"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45138680930000002" green="0.99309605359999997" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <color key="textColor" systemColor="labelColor"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="18"/>
                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                            </textView>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" text="Multiline Label - may be here or not." textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JUe-Ch-kcB">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="39.5" width="374" height="86"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.7552904054556101" blue="0.70372087555305396" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <collectionView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" dataMode="none" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="XmM-Li-1e9">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="127.5" width="374" height="60"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="60" id="ggu-r1-slr"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" scrollDirection="horizontal" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="1gL-6N-ttm">
                                    <size key="itemSize" width="128" height="60"/>
                                    <size key="estimatedItemSize" width="128" height="60"/>
                                    <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                    <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                    <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
                                </collectionViewFlowLayout>
                            </collectionView>
                        </subviews>
                    </stackView>
                </subviews>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstItem="bt1-hr-iCP" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="huS-tm-qA9" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="31M-SL-LEh"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="XQI-LW-mKN" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="huS-tm-qA9" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="AoR-ds-v7X"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="bt1-hr-iCP" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="XQI-LW-mKN" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="PfP-ND-eWY"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="XQI-LW-mKN" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="huS-tm-qA9" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="qbq-Gq-k7L"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="bt1-hr-iCP" secondAttribute="trailing" id="tqQ-o4-hue"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="bt1-hr-iCP" secondAttribute="bottom" priority="750" id="uS0-q9-D7w"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="collectionView" destination="XmM-Li-1e9" id="ks1-BH-srH"/>
                <outlet property="redLabel" destination="JUe-Ch-kcB" id="Lqn-bA-jsh"/>
                <outlet property="textView" destination="laq-Mt-rKJ" id="rx6-zp-jVB"/>
                <outlet property="titleLabel" destination="XQI-LW-mKN" id="k6X-B0-Slx"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="305.79710144927537" y="113.83928571428571"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="labelColor">
            <color white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

---

and this is the source code that produced those screen-caps:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var titleString: String = ""
    var textViewString: String?
    var redLabelString: String?
    var collectionViewData: [String]?
}

class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let label = UILabel()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        // this prevents auto-layout complaints
        let cWidth = label.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 50.0)
        cWidth.priority = .required - 1
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            cWidth,
        ])
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        contentView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    }
}

class SizingCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
    var editCallback: ((UITableViewCell, String) -> ())?
    
    var cvData: [String] = []
    
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var redLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        if collectionView != nil {
            collectionView.register(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myC")
            collectionView.delegate = self
            collectionView.dataSource = self
            
            textView.delegate = self
        }
    }
    func fillData(_ st: MyStruct) {
        titleLabel.text = st.titleString
        
        textView.text = st.textViewString
        
        if let s = st.redLabelString {
            redLabel.text = s
        }
        // hide the red label if it has no text
        redLabel.isHidden = st.redLabelString == nil

        // if st HAS data, do your collection view setup here
        if let d = st.collectionViewData {
            cvData = d
        } else {
            cvData = []
        }
        // hide the collection view if there is no data
        collectionView.isHidden = st.collectionViewData == nil
        
    }
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        // tell the controller the textView was edited
        editCallback?(self, textView.text)
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cvData.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myC", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.label.text = cvData[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    
}

class TestSizingCellTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var myData: [MyStruct] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // create some sample data
        let sampleStrings: [String] = [
            "Short string.",
            "This is a longer string.",
            "This string should be long enough that we'll get word-wrapping.",
        ]
        let sampelData: [[String]] = [
            ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
            ["A", "B", "C - dynamic width cells", "D", "E", "F", "G"],
            ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four - wider", "Five", "Six", "Seven - wider", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"],
        ]
        
        for i in 0..<10 {
            var st = MyStruct()
            st.titleString = "Row \(i)"
            st.textViewString = "Text View \(i): " + sampleStrings[i % sampleStrings.count]
            st.redLabelString = "Red Label \(i): " + sampleStrings[i % sampleStrings.count]
            st.collectionViewData = sampelData[i % sampelData.count]
            myData.append(st)
        }
        
        // let's remove the redLabel text for the 4th row (Row 3)
        myData[3].textViewString = "Red Label will be gone!"
        myData[3].redLabelString = nil

        // let's remove the collection view for the 5th row (Row 4)
        myData[4].redLabelString = "Red Label has text again, so we see it, but collection view will be gone."
        myData[4].collectionViewData = nil
        
        // let's remove both the redLabel and the collection view for the 6th row (Row 5)
        myData[5].textViewString = "Both Red Label and Collection View will be gone!"
        myData[5].redLabelString = nil
        myData[5].collectionViewData = nil
        
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SizingCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "sizingCell")
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sizingCell", for: indexPath) as! SizingCell
        cell.fillData(myData[indexPath.row])
        cell.editCallback = { [weak self] c, s in
            guard let self = self,
                  let idxPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: c)
            else { return }
            self.myData[idxPath.row].textViewString = s
            self.tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
        }
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

---